# VB.NET ReadProcessMemory()

Tags: vb.net

estoy intentando leer valores de direcciones de memoria de un proceso.

De momento me salta el error de que he introducido la dirección de memoria mal.
Es la variable `HPaddr` a la cual le inicio un valor de `005C682C`.

Para leer la dirección de memoria he usado CheatEngine, y la dirección de memoria es la anterior, sin modificar nada: `005C682C`

El código es el siguiente:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal 
dwDesiredAcess As UInt32, ByVal bInheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal 
dwProcessId As Int32) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess 
As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer() As Byte, ByVal 
iSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As 
IntPtr) As Boolean

Private _targetProcess As Process = Nothing 'to keep track of it. not used yet.
Private _targetProcessHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero 'Used for ReadProcessMemory
Private PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS As UInt32 = &H1F0FFF
Private PROCESS_VM_READ As UInt32 = &H10

Private HPaddr As IntPtr = "005C682C"

Public Function TryAttachToProcess(ByVal windowCaption As String) As Boolean
    Dim _allProcesses() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
    For Each pp As Process In _allProcesses
        If pp.MainWindowTitle.ToLower.Contains(windowCaption.ToLower) Then
            'found it! proceed.
            Return TryAttachToProcess(pp)
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to find process '" & windowCaption & ".' Is running?")
    Return False
End Function

Public Function TryAttachToProcess(ByVal proc As Process) As Boolean
    If _targetProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then 'not already attached
        _targetProcess = proc
        _targetProcessHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, _targetProcess.Id)
        If _targetProcessHandle = 0 Then
            TryAttachToProcess = False
            MessageBox.Show("OpenProcess() FAIL! Are you Administrator??")
        Else
            'if we get here, all connected and ready to use ReadProcessMemory()
            TryAttachToProcess = True
            MessageBox.Show("OpenProcess() OK")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Already attached! (Please Detach first?)")
        TryAttachToProcess = False
    End If
End Function

Public Sub DetachFromProcess()
    If Not (_targetProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        _targetProcess = Nothing
        Try
            CloseHandle(_targetProcessHandle)
            _targetProcessHandle = IntPtr.Zero
            MessageBox.Show("MemReader::Detach() OK")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("MemoryManager::DetachFromProcess::CloseHandle error " & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim _myBytes(3) As Byte
    ReadProcessMemory(_targetProcessHandle, HPaddr, _myBytes, 4, vbNull)
    Label2.Text = BitConverter.ToInt32(_myBytes, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TryAttachToProcess("Pinball")
End Sub
End Class
```

El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si le añado comillas a esta prueba, sale el error del principio.

Ojalá puedan ayudarme! Saludos, y muchas gracias!

Comment: El tema es bastante complicado para poder ayudarte. De todas maneras, el código que usas te da algún error? o simplemente no consigues acceder al dato que buscas? Si te da error, edita tu pregunta y pégalo completo

Comment: gracias, se me pasó poner el error... ya lo he editado

Comment: El error es claro. No se puede convertir una cadena de caracteres al tipo Long. Intenta con `Private HPaddr As IntPtr = new IntPtr(0x005C682C);`

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo tu propuesta y el resultado

Comment: Perdona, es que yo siempre programo en C#. En vb.net sería `HPaddr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(&H005C682C)`

Comment: Y para apuntar a esa dirección de memoria, como podría hacer? Por ejemplo, cada vez que accedo a la dirección de memoria XXX se mueve una pinza en el programa Pinball. Podría mover esa pinza a través de este código y no del propio programa Pinball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IntPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.intptr(v=vs.110).aspx) es una estructura que representa un puntero entero a una dirección de memoria.

Tiene 3 constructores:

- IntPtr(Int32)
- IntPtr(Int64)
- IntPtr(*void)

En tu caso, lo quieres es inicializar un `IntPtr` con una dirección en Hexadecimal. Para indicar hexadecimal en Vb.net se usa el prefijo `&H`. Así que debes inicializar la variable de la siguiente manera:

```
Private HPaddr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(&H005C682C)
```

Comment: Exactamente, la solución era:

        Private HPaddr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(&H5C6848)

Muchas gracias!